# Android Studio - where to execute keytool command?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to export my upload certificate. I received an E-Mail from google which says  I should execute this command

2. Export the certificate for that key to PEM format:

   keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks

But it does not say where? I tried it in CMD and in Android Studios internal terminal, but it says it can't find the command.

Comment: are you sure its not scam?

Comment: Yes, it is official. I triggered the reset and had a chat previously

Comment: You are using it in CMD, but keytool is an exe which they assume you have linked to your command, but in reality the keytool command is somewhere in your Folders and you have to replace keytool with the correct Folder where it is. I don't know where it is atm, but that is easy to find. But why should Google want your PEM Key, they already got it? This really Looks like scam, especially since Google introduced they Google sign method

Comment: add what terminal say to you as a response please

Comment: Because there is an error in android studio and my keystore is not working anymore, so I have to reset the key. Thats not scam I triggered the reset myself.

Comment: like this :  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin

Comment: also worth nothing that this process is also required for using the facebook SDK, so it's not a scam :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path to the java jdk bin to your system path, then you can execute the command from CMD or from PowerShell

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27Sesdc_g3o